# How to get the version history of a list using Client Object Model Sharepoint 2010

Tags: list

I want to access the list item history details since I have some multiline fields which are all enabled with append data mode. Also, I want to see if any date is modified after creation of that item and etc. How can I do it through Sharepoint 2010 Client Object Model?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I'm concerned this is not possible, that might be a deal breaker for the project I am working on right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've confirmed that for list items the version history cannot be accessed via the CLOM in SharePoint 2010. I needed to do this to get a running list of comments.We have opted to push the comments out into their own list with a "foreign key" column relating them back to the original item. Since the Silverlight front end is the one going to be used by the end users it does not matter that the comments cannot be seen from the original item.